# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int': How do I compare list items?

Tags: python, list

What I am trying to do is compare the country to the previous two countries and see if they are all different. I'm having a difficult time with storing the values in a list and then comparing them. I tried strings already but couldn't seem to get it right.

unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
is the error I'm getting. Any tips for resolving this?

```
def purchase(amount, day, month, country):
    global history, owed, last_country
    owed += amount
    history += [(days_in_months(month - 1) + day)]
    last_country += [country]
    if history[len(history) - 2] > history[len(history) - 1]:
        return str(error)
    elif all_three_different(country, last_country[len(last_country)-1], last_country[len(last_country-2)]) == True:
        return str(error)
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: please provide some input (i.e. the list) and expected output

Comment: And the traceback, and the values of the parameters and the global vars. I can see four addition operations there, and you haven't given us any information about which one is causing the problem

Comment: Country would be input as a string, for example "France"

Comment: The global variables all equal zero.

Comment: It's the all_three_different trying to compare strings which is causing the problem. The function returns true if all three parameters do not equal each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subtract 2 from a list here:

```
last_country[len(last_country-2)]
```

Note the parentheses! The `last_country-2` expression is *within* the `len()` call. You probably meant to do this:

```
last_country[len(last_country)-2]
```

You do not need to use the length at all though; just negative indices:

```
last_country[-2]
```

This gets you the exact same value; the 1 but last value from the list. Negative indices are automatically subtracted from the length of the list when indexing.

Something else you don't have to do is use `== True`; that is what the `if` / `elif` statement already does for you; just leave that off:

```
if history[-2] > history[-1]:
    return str(error)
elif all_three_different(country, last_country[-1], last_country[-2]):
    return str(error)
else:
    return True
```